# state management model in a jot form clone with react + redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-state-management, jotform

I'm supposed to make a clone of [jot form](https://www.jotform.com/) and for now I just need to make the classic form builder.

so there is left menu which is basically a list of elements, you either select them or directly drag and drop them to the center container. on the right side there is another menu which is for the options of the elements.

The only part I can't figure out is the state management.
the page structure is simple but I need some help on modeling the state. how  should i send options of each different element to the right menu?

Comment: you have few options at least. you can use: 1. Context API, 2. Form manager(react-hook-form - which is also using context api). 3. State management - react-redux/mobx. provide example of code in jsfiddle or codepen and I will help you

Comment: @wentris, i have not started coding yet. my problem is not choosing the right library. it is modeling the process.

Comment: it is a complex and complicated implementation. take a look at React context api, and at a tool - react-hook-form(which is using this feature as well). you can store your common data inside your custom context, and get access to it through useContext hook inside any children component(do not need to pass down any props). I can really help you when you clarify more your point and provide a real example

Comment: @wentris thanks. your help means a lot. Is it ok if I come back after a few days that I have coded something? right now i have no code to share. I'm planning to use redux for the job since it's what JotForm uses.